# Вывести значении mysql колонок (столбцов), которые отличаются только цифрами в имени

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, mysqli, pdo

Нужно вывести значении mysql колонок (столбцов), которые отличаются только цифрами в имени.
Пример имени колонок:

```
id col1 col2 col3 name1 name2 name3
```

Нужно вывести только значении колонок `col1` `col2` `col3` (т.е. должен найти совпадении только начала имени колонки `col`, а цифр могут быть сколько угодно и какие угодно).

Если вручную, то так: `SELECT col1,col2,col3 FROM table_name`, нужно что-то похожее на это: `SELECT col* FROM table_name`, где вместо * подставляются числа, всех подходящих столбцов.

Как это сделать?

Comment: Можно динамически составить запрос используя информацию из метаданных - information_schema.columns

Comment: Если требуется работать с динамическими именами полей - значит, есть проблемы в архитектуре БД. как минимум - денормализация налицо. Хотя, конечно, это может быть тривиальный недостаток фантазии при именовании полей.